# Проблемы с .properties

Tags: jsp, java, локализация

java 
jsp
локализация.
Теги
`<fmt:setBundle basename="locale_en_EN.properties"/>
<fmt:message key="reg" />`
выводит ???reg??? вместо значения.
Это говорит о том что соответствующий файл .properties не найден.
Куда только его не кидал!
В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Может он у тебя называется не locale_en_EN.properties?

Comment: Нет, именно так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файл .properties должен лежать в `classpath` - сделайте внутри вашего JSP небольшую Java инъекцию выводящую текущий ваш `classpath` и положите .properties туда.

Если дело происходит из какой-то IDE то вполне вероятно вы не указываете IDE что надо экспортировать .properties из каталога исходников в каталог `classpath`

Comment: Вы бы не могли поподробнее рассказать вот об этом:

>"Если дело происходит из какой-то IDE то вполне вероятно вы не указываете IDE что надо экспортировать .properties из каталога исходников в каталог classpath"

Я использую эклипс, как указать IDE, что надо экспортировать .properties из каталога исходников в каталог classpath?
И как вывести на jsp текущий класпас, я искал инфу про класпас, что-то не могу понять, как его вывести на странице.

Answer (score 0):

Файлы `.properties` доступны из `classpath`, как уже было сказано. 
Если вы используете maven, лучше их положить в директорию resources от maven или в WEB-INF/classes.